# PHP Curl Returns Blank Page in my Laptop but working fine in my friends Laptop

Tags: php, curl

I have read many similar title questions about PHP CURL return blank page, but none of them worked for me...

The problem is that when I'm sending an cURL query to a website all I get is a blank page.
But this problem just happened im my laptop, i have tried to test in my two friends Laptop and just working fine.

The code i have try is this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJqnGnnnwUQ

I try to grab the http://www.hackforums.net/, it's return blank page.
But when i try the blogspot page , it can grab that website.

Im using Asus a455ln
WampServer Version 2.5
Windows 8.1 Pro

this is the copy of the code

```
<?php

echo grab_page("http://www.hackforums.net/");

function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    //curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELD, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($login);
    unset($login);
}

function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY ) ; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec($ch);

    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($ch);    
}

function post_data($site,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
    $headers = array("Expect:");
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    //curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELD, $data);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec($datapost);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($datapost);
    unset($datapost);
}

?>
```

Comment: Why do you have statements after `return curl_exec($login)`? The `return` statement ends the function, nothing after that will be executed.

Comment: You might want to add `$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );` after the curl_exec and check the http status returned.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in php and curl. I just follow the tutorial in the video, so I just copy paste it to the notes. 
I just try to remove the return and nothing happened.
But the problem is why The Code working fine in my friends laptop,but return blank pages on mya laptop? o_O
@Barmar

Comment: I try it, and nothing happens too o_O @LarryBorsato

Comment: You get nothing returned in $response? Perhaps your request is timing out with no response, though that seems unlikely with a timeout of 40000.

Comment: yes, i got nothing. for additional information, I can grab blogspot like http://andyhide.blogspot.com/ but can't http://www.hackforums.net/. Any help very appriciated. @LarryBorsato

Comment: Ohmygod, the Problem because I'm using Odyssey Access Client Manager to connect to the network in my office. 
When I'm change th connection it's just simply worked.
Thanks anyway! @LarryBorsato